# Conditional subset array between ranges

Tags: julia

I wish to filter data between a specific range.

```
dummy = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

This works for a single condition:

```
dummy[dummy .> 4]
```

If I try set a range:

```
dummy[dummy .> 4 & dummy .< 7]
```

This logic doesnt provide the expected output filtering > 4 and < 7.

This did the trick

```
dummy[(dummy .> 4) .& (dummy .< 7)]
```

Comment: you could write `dummy[4 .< dummy .< 7]` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexing by a boolean array, either `dummy[(4 .< dummy) .&  (dummy .< 7)]` or `dummy[4 .< dummy .< 7]` should work; the parentheses in the first snippet are required due to operator precedence. For additional clarity with larger filters, the generation of the boolean array can be vectorized using the `@.` macro:

```
dummy[@. 4 < dummy < 7]
```

Note that filtering using boolean arrays will allocate memory for the intermediate array; thus, the `filter`/`filter!` functions may come in handy. Both of the following calls are equivalent, with the latter improving readability for larger conditions.

```
filter(x -> 4 < x < 7, dummy)
filter(dummy) do x
    4 < x < 7
end
```

The `filter!` function may be used in place of `filter` if mutation of the existing array is acceptable.